# Different JS files using Rails asset pipeline in development mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I would like to have the non-minified version of JavaScript libraries being used in development, and the minified versions used elsewhere.

How would I go about doing this if I'm using Rails assets?

I'm including like this:

**application.haml**

```
= javascript_include_tag :application
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js
//= require jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js
... and many more
```

Comment: the asset pipeline minifies after combining, so why do you need to add minimized version?

Comment: I did not know that--it doesn't happen in my project. Must be a disabled setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better thing to do is use the `:debug` option

```
= javascript_include_tag "application", debug: Rails.env.development?
```

In debug mode, assets are **not** minified.

If you're actually maintaining 2 versions of each library *(for example, a minified and raw version of jQuery)*, this is unnecessary. If you want to see the raw jQuery source in your browser's console, you should always use the unminified version of the library in combination with the `:debug` option above.

- In development an unminified version of jQuery will be included in it's own `<script>` tag
- in production jQuery will be minified and concatenated with all other assets in `application.js` in a **single** `<script>` tag.

Comment: Thanks, it seems obvious now :)